# Files in S3 bucket with the UUID in Next.js

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, uuid

I need to upload a pdf file application in S3 bucket with UUID in next.js. can anyone help me..?

I'm try to upload files in s3 with unique name and then pass the name it to the node and store it in aws

Comment: is there a code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

NextJS has nothing to do with S3. You need to use [AWS Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/) to upload a file to S3.

You can set the key to be a UUID.

It will look something like this:

```
  const client = new S3Client();
  await client.send(new PutObjectCommand({
     Bucket: YOURBUCKET,
     Key: uuidv4(),
     Body: YOURFILE,
  }));
```